# C++ sibling template classes as template template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, function-templates

I have a binary tree and I am trying to put each depth of nodes in its own linked list.

I have the class templates:

```
template <typename T> 
class Node 
{
    public:
        T data;
};

template <typename T>
class ListNode : public Node<T>
{
    public:
        ListNode * next;
};

template <typename T>
class TreeNode : public Node<T>
{
    public:
        TreeNode * left;
        TreeNode * right;
};
```

To accomplish the task, I planned on using a function template that has `TreeNode<T> * root` as a parameter and returns a `vector<ListNode<T> *>`.

What is the correct way to define the function template?

Not knowing how to approach it, I initially expected something like this to be a way to accomplish this:

```
template <template <typename> class Node, typename T>
std::vector<ListNode<T> *> listify(TreeNode<T> * root)
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

But this does not work.

It seems like the compiler is okay with:

```
template <template <typename> class TreeNode, typename T>
std::vector<ListNode<T> *> listify(TreeNode<T> * root)
{
    // Do stuff...
}
```

Why does this work/what exactly is happening here? Is this the correct way to do this with sibling class templates?

Comment: `TreeNode` does not need to be a template parameter there. As @jarod42 implies, you can just refer to the `TreeNode` class. The only template parameter you need is for the `T` of TreeNode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following should be enough:

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<ListNode<T>*> listify(TreeNode<T>* root)
```

Comment: Thanks! The question I (wrongly) thought I was asking was using templates for the class templates as well. Something like `std::vector<L<T> *> listify (N<T> * root)`. I was confused. Thanks again!